# Me da errores mi código en la consola al correr el codigo

Tags: java

Me da errores mi código en la consola. Estoy probando hacer una calculadora en Java pero me salen varios errores en la consola. Aquí dejo lo que hice y lo que me muestra,

Lo que quiero lograr hacer es una calculadora que primero meta una operación y de ahí pasar esa operación a Notación Polaca Inversa. Finalmente me muestre el resultado. Si alguien me pudiera apoyar se lo agradecería mucho

[image: Lo que me aparece]

```
public class Calcu {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String expresion;
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese la expresión aritmética:");
        expresion = sc.nextLine();
        
        double resultado = evaluarExpresion(expresion);
        
        System.out.println("El resultado es: " + resultado);
    }
    
    public static double evaluarExpresion(String expresion) {
        String[] tokens = expresion.split(" ");
        Stack<Double> pila = new Stack<>();
        
        for (String token : tokens) {
            switch (token) {
                case "+":
                    double a = pila.pop();
                    double b = pila.pop();
                    pila.push(b + a);
                    break;
                case "-":
                    a = pila.pop();
                    b = pila.pop();
                    pila.push(b - a);
                    break;
                case "*":
                    a = pila.pop();
                    b = pila.pop();
                    pila.push(b * a);
                    break;
                case "/":
                    a = pila.pop();
                    b = pila.pop();
                    pila.push(b / a);
                    break;
                case "u-":
                    a = pila.pop();
                    pila.push(-a);
                    break;
                case "^":
                    a = pila.pop();
                    b = pila.pop();
                    pila.push(Math.pow(b, a));
                    break;
       
        return pila.pop();
    }
}
```

[image: Lo que me aparece]

Comment: Hola. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega los errores como texto.

Answer (score 1):

Realicé algunos cambios en tus métodos:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );

  System.out.println( "Ingrese la expresión aritmética:" );
  String expresion = sc.nextLine();
  String[] tokens = expresion.split( " " );

  Stack<String> pila = new Stack<>();
  for( String data : tokens ) {
     pila.push( data );
  }

  Double resultado = evaluarExpresion( pila );
  System.out.println( "El resultado es: " + resultado );
}
```

Como puedes ver, el **Stack** lo creo aquí, y mediante un **for**, le agrego los valores contenidos en **expresión**.
A **evaluarExpresion** le paso como parámetro el **Stack**.

```
public static Double evaluarExpresion( Stack<String> pila ) {
  double b;
  String token = pila.pop();
  double a = Double.parseDouble( pila.pop() );
  switch( token ) {
     case "+":
        b = Double.parseDouble( pila.pop() );
        return b + a;
     case "-":
        b = Double.parseDouble( pila.pop() );
        return b - a;
     case "*":
        b = Double.parseDouble( pila.pop() );
        return b * a;
     case "/":
        b = Double.parseDouble( pila.pop() );
        return b / a;
     case "u-":
        return -1 * a;
     case "^":
        b = Double.parseDouble( pila.pop() );
        return Math.pow( a, b );
     default:
        return NaN;
  }
}
```

Este método es muy simple, hacemos un **pop** a **pila** para obtener el operador.
Luego con el **switch** inicializamos la/s variables numéricas, parseando (con **Double.parseDouble(x)**) lo que quitamos de **pila** con **pop** ya que **pila** contiene cadenas.
Solo resta devolver el valor de la operación.

Nota: la entrada de tener el siguiente formato: "8 9 +", con el operador siempre en último lugar.

Comment: Así a ojo, si primero asignas `a`, luego asignas `token` y luego asignas `b`, cómo es posible que necesites poner `"8 9 +"` si el orden de asignación es `a`, `token`, `b`??

Comment: @Benito-B, excelente corrección, fue un cambio de último momento, y patiné... gracias!!!